# JTable - sorting rendered values

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using custom renderer to render cell values in JTable. When I perform sorting using my own Comparator or TableRowSorter, values are generally sorted using data from the model.

Is there a way to sort columns on rendered cell values instead of original value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I perform sorting using my own Comparator

Then your custom Comparator needs to know what the rendered values will be and sort on those values. This means you need to convert the data from the TableModel to the rendered value in your Comparator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a `TableRowSorter`, look at the tutorial for an example:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

Answer (score -1):

SwingX rendering mechanism does so automatically (WYSIWYS - what you see is what you sort/search). The only thing you have to supply is a StringValue: that's the SwingX speak for defining the representation of cell content

```
JXTable table = new JXTable(myModel); // creates a RowSorter automatically
StringValue sv = new StringValue() {
     @Override
     public String getString(Object value) {
          if (value instanceof MyClass) {
              return // whatever string you want to create from the valuee's property
          } 
          return StringValues.TO_STRING.getString(value);
     }
};
table.setDefaultRenderer(MyClass.class, new DefaultTableRenderer(sv));
```